# How to fire repeated local notification between two specific time

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, swiftui, localnotification

Im trying to build an app that sends local notification every day between specific times. For instance, between 8AM and 10PM every 1 hour. I could fire a notification using `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` every 1 hr or `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` at specified date and time, However I couldn't find a solution to fire notification/reminder at specified start time and repeat it every 1 hr until end time. Any guidance or help is much appreciated.

Here is what I tried so far.

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var userDetails: UserDetails
    
    init(userDetails: UserDetails) {
        self.userDetails = UserDetails()
        if let data = userData.retrieveData() {
            self.userDetails.user = data
        }
        Notifications.shared.scheduleNotification(userData: self.userDetails.user)
    }
    
    let width: CGFloat = 20.0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
```

//App Delegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        Notifications.shared.notificationRequest()
        Notifications.shared.notificationSettings()
        return true
    }
```

//Other funtions

```
 func scheduleNotification(userData: User) {
        var wakeUpTime = userData.wakeupTime
        var bedTime = userData.bedTime
        
        while wakeUpTime < bedTime {
            wakeUpTime = wakeUpTime.addingTimeInterval( 60.0)
            scheduleNotification(at: wakeUpTime, body: "Testing Notification", titles: "Reminder")
        }
}

func scheduleNotification(at date: Date, body: String, titles:String) {

        let triggerDaily = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour,.minute,.second], from: date)

        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDaily, repeats: true)

        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = titles
        content.body = body
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "NotificationAt-\(date))", content: content, trigger: trigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Still not sure what you're looking for exactly. Could you maybe add more clarity.

Comment: @Frankenstein Simply I want to send notification or reminder that starts for example at 8 AM and repeats every 1 hour until 8 PM.

Comment: And doesn't shedule notification method do exactly that?